# subsetting in r based on a vector of conditions

Tags: r, subset

This is a restatement of my poorly worded previous question.  (To those who replied to it, I appreciate your efforts, and I apologize for not being as clear with my question as I should have been.)  I have a large dataset, a subset of which might look like this:

```
a<-c(1,2,3,4,5,1)
b<-c("a","b","a","b","c","a")
c<-c("m","f","f","m","m","f")
d<-1:6
e<-data.frame(a,b,c,d)
```

If I want the sum of the entries in the fourth column based on a specific condition, I could do something like this:

```
attach(e)
total<-sum(e[which(a==3 & b=="a"),4])
detach(e)
```

However, I have a "vector" of conditions (call it condition_vector), the first four elements of which look more like this:

```
a==3 & b == "a"
a==2
a==1 & b=="a" & c=="m"
c=="f"
```

I'd like to create a "generalized" version of the "total" formula above that produces a results_vector of totals by reading in the condition_vector of conditions.  In this example, the first four entries in the results_vector would be calculated conceptually as follows:

```
results_vector[1]<-sum(e[which(a==3 & b=="a"),4])
results_vector[2]<-sum(e[which(a==2),4])
results_vector[3]<-sum(e[which(a==1 & b=="a" & c=="m"),4])
results_vector[4]<-sum(e[which(c=="f"),4])
```

My actual data set has more than 20 variables.  So each record in the condition_vector can contain anywhere from 1 to more than 20 conditions (as opposed to between 1 and 3 conditions, used in this example).

Is there a way to accomplish this other than using a parse(eval(text= ... approach (which takes a long time to run on a relatively small dataset)?

Thanks in advance for any help you can provide (and again, I apologize that I wasn't as clear as I should have been last time around).

Spark

Comment: I would recommend not using `attach`. It could lead to R programming woes.

Answer (score 3):

Here using a  solution using `eval(parse(text=..)` here, even if obviously you find it slow:

```
cond <- c('a==3 & b == "a"','a==2','a==1 & b=="a" & c=="x"','c=="f"')
names(cond) <- cond
results_vector <- lapply(cond,function(x)
                              sum(dat[eval(parse(text=x)),"d"]))

$`a==3 & b == "a"`
[1] 3

$`a==2`
[1] 2

$`a==1 & b=="a" & c=="m"`
[1] 1

$`c=="f"`
[1] 11
```

The advantage of naming your conditions vector is to access to your results by condition.

```
results_vector[cond[2]]
 $`a==2`
  [1] 2
```

Comment: This is actually a simpler statement than the one I had, so thanks for that.  Unfortunately, it still (as you predicted) runs much more slowly than I was hoping it could.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a function that takes as arguments the condition in each column (if no condition in a column, then `NA` as argument) and sums in a selected column of a selected data.frame:

```
    conds.by.col <- function(..., sumcol, DF)  #NA if not condition in a column
    {
     conds.ls <- list(...)

     res.ls <- vector("list", length(conds.ls))
     for(i in 1: length(conds.ls))
      {
       res.ls[[i]] <- which(DF[,i] == conds.ls[[i]])
      }

     res.ls <- res.ls[which(lapply(res.ls, length) != 0)]

     which_rows <- Reduce(intersect, res.ls)

     return(sum(DF[which_rows , sumcol]))
    }
```

Test:

```
    a <- c(1,2,3,4,5,1)
    b <- c("a", "b", "a", "b", "c", "a")
    c <- c("m", "f", "f", "m", "m", "f")
    d <- 1:6
    e <- data.frame(a, b, c, d)

    conds.by.col(3, "a", "f", sumcol = 4, DF = e)
    #[1] 3
```

For multiple conditions, `mapply`:

```
    #all conditions in a data.frame:
    myconds <- data.frame(con1 = c(3, "a", "f"),
                          con2 = c(NA, "a", NA),
                          con3 = c(1, NA, "f"),
                          stringsAsFactors = F)

    mapply(conds.by.col, myconds[1,], myconds[2,], myconds[3,], MoreArgs = list(sumcol = 4, DF = e))

    #con1 con2 con3 
    #   3   10    6
```

I guess "efficiency" isn't the first you say watching this, though...

Comment: This is an interesting thought, Alexis, thanks.  Unfortunately, my real data set has 20+ columns and the condition_vector contains hundreds (or at times thousands) of conditions.  So this may stretch past the limits of R's memory capacity.  Is there a simple function that could take the condition vector as I have it described, and "map" it to a 2-dimensional data frame (or perhaps even a 2 dimensional character matrix) that looks like the input you have (i.e., put NAs where there are no conditions and map the conditions that apply to their respective columns)?  Thanks again.

Comment: @SparkyJ: Your "condition vector" is exactly like `cond` in agstudy's answer? Also, 1) your "condition vector" includes only equalities (`==`) 2) it includes only one condition per column (e.g `a == 1 OR 2`, or always `a == 1`)?

Comment: It's derived using the "paste" function, so it can be made to look a little different, if that would help.  The condition vector does include only equalities (no inequalities).  And though there can be any number of columns included in the condition, each condition only has one variable value for each column used.  Thanks.